# Conditional I and Conditional II

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

> Conditional I Active: Rita    would write a letter.
>
> Passive:  A letter    would be written    by Rita.
>
> Conditional II    Active: Rita    would have written  a letter.
>
> Passive:  A letter    would have been written by Rita.

What's the difference? between **would be written** and **would have written**

Comment: From the temporal perspective of the sentences, the first describes the future, while the second describes the past.

Answer (score -1):

As your sentences indicate, **would be written** is a passive construction whose subject is *a letter*. And **would have written** is in the active voice with *Rita* as the subject.

Your conditional sentences are misnamed. They are examples of what are typically called Conditional 2 (*Rita would write a letter*) and Conditional 3 (*Rita would have written a letter*) respectively.

This is more obvious if you add a protasis (*if-clause*):

- Rita *would write* a letter if she *had* time (*but she doesn't have time*).
- Rita *would have written* a letter if she *had had* time (*but she didn't have time*).

The passive apodoses (main clauses) can be followed by the same protases:

- A letter *would be written* by Rita if she *had* time.
- A letter *would have been written* by Rita if she *had had* time.

The same sentences in the so-called Conditional 1 are:

- Rita *will write* a letter if she *has* time.
- A letter *will be written* by Rita if she *has* time.

Comment: A letter would be written by Rita if she had time.(but she doesn't have time) or (but she didn't have time) ?

Comment: @Vikea Mahun. It needs to be _A letter would be written by Rita if she had time (but she doesn't have time)_ This exemplifies one use of Conditional 2 - namely to express a counterfactual _about the present_. In this case the counterfactual (i.e. what is not true) is that Rita has time. On this basis your alternative _A letter would be written by Rita if she had time (but she didn't have time)_ does not work because the bracketed clause is about past time rather than present time.

Comment: well, 

> Passive: A letter would be written by Rita.
>  Conditional 2 Passive voice
_________________________________________

> Passive: A letter would have been written by Rita. 
Conditional 3  passive voice
______________________
isn't it?